# Groupmapping does not work for AD groups

Tags: linux, active-directory, ldap, samba, winbind

We have an ActiveDirectory where we get our users from.
So authentication on the linux machine works over pam.

We managed this part to work so far, **but we need all users to be part of the local group "users"**.
This works as far as I understand with group mapping.

**My SIDs are:**

```
SID for local machine MYSERVER is: S-1-5-21-1487948860-3705201071-3703638889  
SID for domain MYDOMAIN is: S-1-5-21-1960408961-115176313-682003330
```

I created the group mapping with:

```
myserver:~# net groupmap add ntgroup="Domain Users" rid=513 unixgroup=users
```

**The groupmapping looks like this:**

```
myserver:~# net groupmap list -v

Domain Users
        SID       : S-1-5-21-1487948860-3705201071-3703638889-513
        Unix gid  : 100
        Unix group: users
        Group type: Domain Group
        Comment   : Domain Unix group
Administrators
        SID       : S-1-5-32-544
        Unix gid  : 10029
        Unix group: BUILTIN\administrators
        Group type: Local Group
        Comment   :
Users
        SID       : S-1-5-32-545
        Unix gid  : 12929
        Unix group: BUILTIN\users
        Group type: Local Group
        Comment   :
```

But when I login as an AD user I am not in the group users. All AD groups are shown correct and also the groups "BUILTIN\users" and "BUILTIN\administrator" are shown but no group "users"

I also tried

```
myserver:~# net groupmap delete ntgroup="Domain Users"
myserver:~# net groupmap delete ntgroup="Users"
myserver:~# net groupmap add ntgroup="Users" rid=545 unixgroup=users
```

But this seem to have no effect (smbd restart, winbindd restart executed).
The user is still in the group "BUILTIN\users" and has no entry for "users"

I think I missed some important configuration step but don't know what this could be.
Any help is highly appreciated!

**We use samba version 3.6.3 on a SLES 11 kernel 3.0.76**

**==EDIT== 07.04.2016 15:34**

I tried to map two non standard groups.
AD group is grp_production, local linux group should be games

```
myserver:~# net groupmap add ntgroup="grp_production" rid=20443 unixgroup=games
```

Result is

```
myserver:~# net groupmap list -v
..
grp_production (S-1-5-21-1960408961-115176313-682003330-20443) -> games
..
```

Then I login as a user (member of the AD group grp_production) on the linux machine.

```
myserver:~# groups | grep games
```

No games group to find :-(

**==EDIT 08.04.2016 07:39==**
The only error I found in the logs was in /var/log/samba/log.winbindd-idmap

```
[2016/04/07 13:54:25.146170,  1] ../librpc/ndr/ndr.c:284(ndr_print_function_debug)
       wbint_Sid2Gid: struct wbint_Sid2Gid
          in: struct wbint_Sid2Gid
              dom_name                 : NULL
              sid                      : *
                  sid                      : S-1-5-21-1960408961-115176313-682003330-28693
[2016/04/07 13:54:25.146221, 10] winbindd/idmap_util.c:234(idmap_sid_to_gid)
  idmap_sid_to_gid: sid = [S-1-5-21-1960408961-115176313-682003330-28693], domain = ''
[2016/04/07 13:54:25.146247, 10] winbindd/idmap.c:507(idmap_backends_sid_to_unixid)
  idmap_backends_sid_to_unixid: domain = '', sid = [S-1-5-21-1960408961-115176313-682003330-28693]
[2016/04/07 13:54:25.146267, 10] winbindd/idmap.c:376(idmap_find_domain)
  idmap_find_domain called for domain ''
[2016/04/07 13:54:25.146290,  1] winbindd/idmap.c:209(idmap_init_domain)
  invalid range '100' specified for domain '*'
[2016/04/07 13:54:25.146308, 10] winbindd/idmap_util.c:260(idmap_sid_to_gid)
  idmap_backends_sid_to_unixid failed: NT_STATUS_NONE_MAPPED
[2016/04/07 13:54:25.146330, 10] lib/gencache.c:183(gencache_set_data_blob)
  Adding cache entry with key = IDMAP/SID2GID/S-1-5-21-1960408961-115176313-682003330-28693 and timeout = Thu Apr  7 13:56:25 2016
```

I 'grepped' all log for "games" and "grp_production" with no result.

Comment: Please provide some information for downvote reason. I put an immense effort into this question. If something is missing, please ask, I'll add it (as already did many times) to the question.

Answer (score 1):

They are well know sids for builtin groups - but I think they can be offset if there is a domain trust, that is where there are 2 or more BUILTIN/users

can you verify the the sid for the AD group in Powershell

```
Get-ADGroup -Identity users | select sid
```

see if there are any issues with listing users on the samba server

```
net usersidlist
```

one other thing is - is the users group already mapped to something?

```
net groupmap list
```

if the group is already mapped to something then you don't pass the rid value, rid is used to 'add' group, drop the rid if you are just 'modifying'

```
 net groupmap modify ntgroup='Domain Users' unixgroup='users'
```

Comment: All AD-Groups are imported and assigned to the right user under linux. All I need in addition is, that all "Domain Users" are in the linux local group "users". Your approach is exactly what I describe in my question.

Comment: I was pointing out that this command wont work net groupmap add ntgroup="Users" rid=545 unixgroup=users - if the unix group 'users' is mapped to something already - can you show the output of net groupmap list?

Comment: I posted already net groupmap list

Comment: it would be useful to see logs for samba and winbind, have you looked in the users group and have you tried mapping to a non native group such as 'test'?

Comment: I added the testcase with a non native group. Which parts in the logs of winbind and samba are relevant? These files are to big to post here...

Comment: what happenedd in the test case - were members of domain users made members of the test group? - I would configure the log level to 'debug' in both services and then look in the logs for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your `net groupmap add` command added the local machine's SID prefix to your RID, so it actually mapped the "Domain Users" group of your local machine which makes no sense.

Either tell the `net` command that your RID refers to the domain by specifying the appropriate `type` option:

```
net groupmap add ntgroup="Domain Users" rid=513 type=domain unixgroup=users
```

or specify the full SID:

```
net groupmap add ntgroup="Domain Users" sid=S-1-5-21-1960408961-115176313-513 unixgroup=users
```

You may have to delete the erroneous mapping first.